# Are LazyH & V grids performant for lots of data?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Apple’s documentation says that for the LazyVGrids and LazyHGrids that items are created only as needed. Are they disposed of when needed? Am wondering specifically if they are a performant SwiftUI version of collection views that could be used for production. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried a few simple tests to see how they perform for your needs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are performant, especially compared to just using a `VStack`. However - the cells aren't disposed of and recreated later, dequeuing like you might know of in UIKit. The lazy loading only helps for when the rows are first rendered, which most of them won't be.

You can test this with just making a really massive list of views, where a random number gets generated each time the view is created:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< 100000) { i in
                    ForEach(0 ..< 100) { j in
                        if j == 0 {
                            Text("SPACER: \(Int.random(in: 1 ... 100))")
                        } else {
                            Text("index: \(j) - \(i)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once these random numbers are generated, you can see they don't refresh or change after scrolling from the top to the bottom.

This list has 10 million items, which is orders of magnitude more than you want to display. Although it does run a bit slowly, it is still on the verge of usable. From my testing this example when scrolling from top to bottom used about 400MB of memory, far more than you want to ever use.

I think `LazyVStack` is perfectly good for almost all use cases. You should usually try limit the number of items anyway - since you can always create a paging system if needed, like an automatic loading of more views when you scroll to the bottom.

This is a stress-test, and you should not have near this many rows in a real use case.